# How to find its solution ? For some unknowns $a,b,c$ it is given that, $(a+b)(a+c)= 30$ , $(b+a)(b+c)= 35$, $(c+a)(c+b)= 42$ Then $ a+b+c=?$

Tags: linear-algebra

For some unknowns $a,b,c$ it is given that,
$$(a+b)(a+c)= 30$$
$$(b+a)(b+c)= 35$$
$$(c+a)(c+b)= 42$$
Then $a+b+c=?$
I tried to solve it by using the formula for $(a+b+c)^2$ but it isn't helping.

Comment: Do you know whether you are restricted to the integers? If so the problem is pretty easy.

Comment: The solution for the system of equations is not unique, so it's not possible to determine the value of $a+b+c$

Comment: There are two solutions:  $(a,b,c) = (2, 3, 4)$ or $(a,b,c) = (-2,-3,-4)$ so $ a + b + c $ can be $9$ or $-9$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = a + b, v = a + c, w = b + c $, then

$uv = 30$

$uw = 35 $

$vw = 42 $

Dividing we get

$w/v = 7/6 $

$u/v = 5/6 $

so $(u, v, w) = t (5, 6, 7) $

plugging this into $uv = 30$ gives $ t = \pm 1$

It follows that $(a + b) + (a + c) + (b + c) = 2 (a + b + c) = u + v + w = 18 t $

Hence, $a + b+ c = \pm 9 $

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b)(a+c)=30=5\cdot 6$

$(a+b)(b+c)=35=5 \cdot 7$

$(a+c)(b+c)=42=6 \cdot 7$

Try factoring. By inspection $a+b=5. a+c=6. b+c=7$.

Now you have 3 equations in 3 unknowns and usual methods of linear algebra should work.

---

$a^2+ab+ac+bc=30$

$ab+ac+b^2+bc=35$

$ab+ac+bc+c^2=42$

$b^2-a^2=5$

$c^2-b^2=7$

$c^2-a^2=12$

$(b-a)(b+a)=5$

$(c-b)(c+b)=7$

If restricted to the integers then since 5 is prime $b-a=1 $ .

What can you tell from there?

Comment: you found one solution, how do you know there isn't others? EG The negatives work. How do you know that there aren't non-integer solutions?